# Removing border left when removing color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I'm trying to remove the background from a JPG.

I'm using `Selection -> Color range` to select the background color and remove it, but when I select it and remove it, a little border remains on the picture.

I.E. this image:

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

Is there a way to fully remove background from the image without leaving that border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways that you can make this selection neater. If you had a tablet to work with it would improve your precision and you would be able to use the pen tool to replicate your shape completely from scratch, making the result flawless.

Since you are specifically asking about making a selection, here's a way to improve it.

Select > Color Range

[image: Color Range]

Above selection has the artifacts that you describe in your question.

---

1. Select > Color Range + Fuzziness (200)

[image: Color Range + Fuzziness]

Above selection is much smoother. When making your color range selection you can drag the fuzziness to max (or where you think is appropriate).

---

1. Select > Color Range + Fuzziness
2. Select > Modify > Feather

[image: Feather]

Above selection where I added some feather (3px) was way too much and didn't turn out quite well.

---

1. Select > Color Range + Fuzziness
2. Select > Modify > Smooth

[image: Smooth]

Above selection is quite neat, I simply modified the selection to add 2 pixles of smoothness. It will bend the edges a bit but the overall result seems much nicer. If you are concerned about that you can change that to 1px smoothness and also add 1 px feather which will give you a similar result.

---

This way you can tamper with your selection before you remove the red background - change some settings until you feel happy with it.

Comment: Which Photoshop version are you using? I don't have a "Color range + Fuzziness" in the "Select" menu

Comment: I'm using CS6. You need to click on Select menu, then on the Color Range option. When the window of Color Range appears it will have a bunch options. One of the bars in the Color Range window is called Fuzziness and you can drag that up or down.

Answer (score 0):

when you are removing a section, most JPG files will have this situation in result, because color processing is applied on pixels (you'll have better result in better quality files) but it will not happen on vector files (like vectors exported to .tif)
i suggest you to try two other ways:

1. select the area you want to remove yourself with select tools (as soft as you can) then remove it.
2. if you did not select areas yourself, use blending options (like applying stroke and other stuffs) to have more soft edges in result

Comment: Using the select tools, how can I enable anti aliasing? I always get pixeled results, it would be good if I could enable anti aliasing when deleting areas

Comment: im using Photoshop CS6 and there is anti alias checkbox when you are using select tool (it is disabled on rectangle select tool, because its rectangle and there is no hard edges!), by the way have eyes on Feather feature when you are using select tool, it'll help you (its beside anti alias checkbox)